# AWS Vue Amplify - PreBuilt Sign-Out Component Missing

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, aws-amplify, gridsome, aws-amplify-vue

I have Amplify with Cognito signing in users on my Gridsome Vue app and working as expected, but I noticed that the "Sign Out" button will only show up if it is not wrapped in `<amplify-authenticator>` tags. Is the documentation just out-dated or is something broken?

Example, instead of:

```
<amplify-authenticator>
    <amplify-sign-out></amplify-sign-out>
</amplify-authenticator>
```

I am writing:

```
<amplify-sign-out></amplify-sign-out>
```

Which works.

This doesn't follow [the docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/ui/auth/authenticator/q/framework/vue) but other than that it seems to be working as expected.

Here is how I am adding Amplify to my Gridsome project in main.js:

```
import Amplify, * as AmplifyModules from "aws-amplify"
import { AmplifyPlugin, components } from "aws-amplify-vue"
import aws_exports from "./aws-exports"
import "@aws-amplify/ui-vue"
Amplify.configure(aws_exports)
```

...

```
export default function(Vue, { router, head, isClient, appOptions }) {


    // Expose this.$Amplify in components
    Vue.use(AmplifyPlugin, AmplifyModules)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you successfully sign into the Authenticator component, you will then see the "Sign Out" button with the example you shared.

```
<amplify-authenticator>
    <amplify-sign-out></amplify-sign-out>
</amplify-authenticator>
```

Placing `<amplify-sign-out></amplify-sign-out>` button outside of the `<amplify-authenticator>` tags will make it so that "Sign Out" always appears.